# Solving Equations with multiple Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering how to solve equations with multiple functions, for example $\ln(x) + \sin(x) = 0$, without using a graphing calculator.

Comment: Do you know Newton’s root finding method? This will definitely get you there.

Comment: In general equations like this will not have a "nice" solution.

Comment: You can't really get exact roots unless you are really lucky with the equation you can either use Numerical Methods (Newton-Raphson etc.) to find or for less accurate one use polynomial series approximation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, transcendental equations require numerical methods. This is already the case for the "simple" $x=\cos(x)$.

*Assuming* that there is only one root, inspection is good. Dor example, you look for the zero of $$f(x)=\log(x)-\sin(x)$$ Then $$f(0)=-\infty$$ $$f(1)=-\sin(1) <0$$  $$f(e)=1-\sin(e) >0$$ So, there is a root in $[1,e]$.

Now, start Newton method say at the midpoint of the interval that is to say $x_0=\frac {1+e}2$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.859140914 \\
 1 & 2.270940353 \\
 2 & 2.219823981 \\
 3 & 2.219107294 \\
 4 & 2.219107149
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.